# No index on the url_rewrite table

Tags: database, url-rewrite, magento2.2.6

Is there any reason why there is no index on the `entity_id` column on the `url_rewrite` table? Or on `entity_id` and `entity_type`?
The only index I see is on `entity_id` and `store_id`.
I understand that that usually a select is done on `entity_id` AND `store_id` but still...
Side question... 
are there any drawbacks if I add this index myself?

For the record, this is what `show create table url_rewrite` shows:

```
CREATE TABLE `url_rewrite` (
  `url_rewrite_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Rewrite Id',
  `entity_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity type code',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `request_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Request Path',
  `target_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Target Path',
  `redirect_type` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Redirect Type',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Description',
  `is_autogenerated` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is rewrite generated automatically flag',
  `metadata` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Meta data for url rewrite',
  PRIMARY KEY (`url_rewrite_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID` (`request_path`,`store_id`),
  KEY `URL_REWRITE_TARGET_PATH` (`target_path`),
  KEY `URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID_ENTITY_ID` (`store_id`,`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Url Rewrites'
```

Comment: I don't think any drawback over on add of `entity_id`.Magento already add index at 2.3

Comment: i  have checked  at also at 2.2.6. index key exists on `entity_id`.On which you donot see any index key?

Comment: @AmitBera I updated the question with how my url_rewrite table looks like. I checked on 2 instances of 2.2.6 that I have. Maybe my db is corrupted.

Comment: In 2.3 there is also no index on `entity_id`. Just the composed index of `store_id` and `entity_id`. I don't think your db is corrupted :-)

Comment: yes, both  2.2.6 and  2.3 has composed index for store_id and entity_id

Comment: @Marius,  guess that composed it good for health of magento 2 . See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349824/2940291 ,compose index means less disk size and less index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and added my index on `entity_id`. It made a significant difference for my custom import that relied only on `entity_id` lookups and found no other downsides in the last 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this has been addressed in [Magento core](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/badea3978a104bf54266540cd5e427e3dd5000cc#diff-ad9e1fc5394eabf1b2f8c0bfdecfdfbd) now and released with Magento 2.3.4